# Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gmavenplus

We upgraded to Spring Boot 3.2.2 which uses Spring Framework 6.0.2 and know that they removed a class that would use byte code to determine parameter names to @PathVariables and @RequestParams, I tried to find all of them and type in the names of the parameters in all our Controllers, and I got them all, but still getting this error somewhere. We are using Groovy, so our maven plugin is the Groovy plugin, to the Java plugin, so the solutions given in the Spring documentation does not cover the groovy plugin. But I have also tried to add the -parameters configuration into the Groovy plugin with

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parameters>true</parameters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>addSources</goal>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                        <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

but we are still getting these errors.

How do we fix this?

Comment: it requires going out of how it normally builds and do a fresh mvn clean install so that it can generate all the stubs from scratch. However, there is still an exception related to a different upgrade issue that I will create a new Post for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is our solution.

1. Even if you are using the GMavenPlus plugin to generate Java stubs and compile, you also have to add the Maven Compiler Plugin

   ```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```

2. Then you have to run man clean install so that anything already built, will be rebuilt with using the -parameters argument to the Java compiler.